# Term for when work gets passed around instead of being executed

Tags: terminology

At work, I see a lot of this phenomena: work gets passed around instead of someone taking autonomy and seeing its execution. For example:

Task: Arrange meetup for grant awardees in the Lounge area. 
This task gets executed by doing the following sub-tasks:

1. Fix a time
2. Email grant awardees and relevant people to notify the meetup
3. actually convene at the said time and date.

But my co-worker, always uses words like "we have to decide what time", "we have to decide *how* to execute this". She terms it "team effort" which I think simply delays execution of task by talking needlessly about things that can get done by one person taking decision and asking for a vote, as opposed to everyone leaving their work and convening for just this "deciding".

How do I accurately phrase this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say, ***beating around the bush***.

> beat around the bush
>
> : to speak evasively or misleadingly, ***or to stall or waste time***.
> To flush pheasants and other birds so they could be shot, British
> gamekeepers hired beaters who would swing sticks at likely places
> where the birds might be lurking. Not to go directly to such foliage
> but to work around it instead gave the impression of wasting time or
> not trying very hard to raise the birds; hence, beating around the
> bush. [Endangered Phrases by Steven D. Price Copyright © 2011 by Steven D. Price](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Beat+around+the+bush)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the term ***[dilatory](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dilatory):***

> - intended to cause delay, gain time, or defer decision:
>     ***a dilatory strategy.***

(dictionary.reference.com)

Answer (score 2):

I think the idiom you are looking for is:

**" *Passing the buck* "**

[Idioms.online - Pass the buck](https://www.idioms.online/pass-the-buck/)

[Buck passing - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_passing)

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using [***indecisive***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/indecisive) which means:

> (Of a person) not able to make decisions quickly and effectively

Your co-worker in your example shows *indecisiveness* by asking others to decide what is already written in proper operating procedure or manual.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]